# install and configure solr in openshift

Tags: solr, tomcat7, openshift

I am trying to follow [this link](http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/how-to-get-solr-up-and-running-on-openshift/) for setting up solr in Openshift, but I guess the version given in the example is old. the directories given in the documentation are not working properly.

So my question is, How to install Solr in Openshift using tomcat-7 or other Cartridges ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what errors your getting I would recommend taking a look at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-java-tomcat-application-for-free-on-openshifts-paas to get tomcat up and running. From there to deploy a war file its as simple as:

1) clone your repo
2) remove the pom.xml file from the root directory of your repo
3) add your war to the webapps/ dir of your repo
4) do git add/commit/push

Comment: No I am getting an error in jboss log 
    SEVERE: Context [/solr] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: There were many other changes that I had to make, But now its working Proper, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following QuickStart from LogicalSpark to make things easier to get up and running with Solr in OpenShift:
https://github.com/LogicalSpark/openshift-solr-quickstart